# Logicproof dashed boxes for Natural Deduction

Tags: tables, logic

I have been using the [Logicproof](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logicproof) package to write proofs in Fitch style. It creates environments using tabular to make writing proofs less bothersome.

I can't seem to figure out how to create a dashed box in a subproof as in this example:

[image: Natural deduction example]

This is what I have so far. The second subproof should however use a dashed box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{logicproof}{2}
    \begin{subproof}
        \square p \land \square q & assumption\\
        \square p & $\land \mathrm{e}_1$ 1\\
        \square q & $\land \mathrm{e}_2$ 1\\
        \begin{subproof} %This should have a dashed box
            p & $\square \mathrm{e}$ 2\\
            q & $\square \mathrm{e}$ 3\\
            p \land q & $\land \mathrm{i}$ 4, 5
        \end{subproof}
        \square (p \land q) & $\square \mathrm{i}$ 4--6
    \end{subproof}
    \square p \land \square q \to \square (p \land q) & $\to \mathrm{i}$ 1--7
\end{logicproof}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a dashed subproof using logicproof?

If that is not possible how would one go about creating an environment similar to the subproof environment?

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody has answered this in almost a month, I'm going to post my partial solution in the hope that somebody else will take up the challenge.

The package is using a `tabular` environment, basically, to construct the proof. It uses `\cline` to draw the horizontal lines. So, if we can substitute dashed lines, we could get half of the problem done.

`arydshln` supports dashed horizontal and vertical rules in `tabular` and `array` environments. So we can substitute its `\cdashline{}` for the standard `\cline{}`.

We do this by making a modified copy of `logicproof`'s command `\lp@cr@clines`, which we call `\lp@cr@cdashlines`, and a modified copy of `logicproof`'s environment `subproof`, which we call `subproofd`. `subproofd` uses `\lp@cr@cdashlines` where `subproof` uses `\lp@cr@clines`, and `\lp@cr@cdashlines` uses `\cdashline{}` where `\lp@cr@clines` uses `cline{}`.

The upshot of this is that we can use `subproofd` in place of `subproof` to typeset a sub-proof whose box's horizontal lines are dashed rather than continuous.

[image: half-dashed box]

Obviously, the remaining problem is to make the vertical lines of the box dashed. The problem is that `arydshln` supports vertical dashed rules by providing an alternative to `|` for `tabular`/`array` specifications.

But `logicproof` does not use this mechanism to draw the vertical lines of its boxes as its standard column specification shows:

```
 {{r@{~~~}*{#1}{l}@{~}>{$}l<{$}@{~~~~}l@{~}*{#1}{r}}}
```

Instead, it uses `\vline` and I'm not sure how to make *these* dashed in the `subproofd` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\nec}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\square}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lp@cr@cdashlines}{% modified copy of lp@cr@clines
  \lp@set@clines%
  \lp@orig@arraycr%
  \cdashline{\value{lp@cline@1}-\value{lp@cline@2}}%
}
\newenvironment{subproofd}{% modified copy of subproof
  \ifthenelse{%
    \value{lp@total@nests}>\value{lp@nested}%
  }{% All is well; don't do anything.
  }{%
    \PackageError{logicproof}{Too many nested subproofs!}{%
      Increase the maximum number of nested subproofs allowed
      in the current logicproof environment.%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup%
  \lp@stop@proof@line%
  \lp@orig@arraycr%
  \lp@add@space%
  \lp@go@up@a@line%
  \stepcounter{lp@nested}%
  \lp@cr@cdashlines%
  &%
  \lp@continue@proof@line%
}{%
  \ifthenelse{%
    0<\value{lp@nested}%
  }{% All is well; don't do anything.
  }{%
    \PackageError{logicproof}{Cannot end a subproof before it begins}{%
      You must have a \protect\begin{subproof} before you can use %
      \protect\end{subproof}.%
    }%
  }%
  \lp@stop@proof@line%
  \lp@cr@cdashlines%
  \addtocounter{lp@nested}{-1}%
  \lp@extend@space%
  \lp@start@proof@line%
  \begingroup%
  \def\@currenvir{subproofd}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{logicproof}{2}
    \begin{subproof}
        \nec p \land \nec q & assumption\\
        \nec p & $\land \mathrm{e}_1$ 1\\
        \nec q & $\land \mathrm{e}_2$ 1\\
        \begin{subproofd} %This should have a dashed box
            p & $\nec \mathrm{e}$ 2\\
            q & $\nec \mathrm{e}$ 3\\
            p \land q & $\land \mathrm{i}$ 4, 5
        \end{subproofd}
        \nec (p \land q) & $\nec \mathrm{i}$ 4--6
    \end{subproof}
    \nec p \land \nec q \to \nec (p \land q) & $\to \mathrm{i}$ 1--7
\end{logicproof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is even more that the verticals are also being drawn using loops and you'd need to distinguish which level of the loop should get which kind of line, I think. I don't really understand what it is doing, exactly.